# Looking for a solution to add Video/Voice call for my cordova app?

Tags: cordova, webrtc, hybrid-mobile-app

I need to do Video/Voice call over my app if users connect with same WiFi?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to try ConnectyCube Cordova code samples and SDKs for chat messaging and video calling

https://connectycube.com/2018/07/06/connectycube-apache-cordova-phonegap-code-samples-have-been-released/

They provide JS SDK for Cordova/PhoneGap apps and have some pretty simple code samples:

- [Text Chat code sample for Cordova](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/code-samples-chat-cordova)
- [Video Chat code sample for Cordova](https://developers.connectycube.com/js/code-samples-videochat-cordova)

Everything is cross-platform: it works well and similar on iOS, Android and Web browser environments.

Answer (score 0):

Here the link for reference :

https://quickblox.com/blog/quickblox-unveils-apache-cordova-phonegap-chat-and-video-calling-webrtc-code-samples/

Comment: too old and not up to date
du not support the latest Cordova Version